# How to block Google Analytics from tracking specific query parameters?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a URL like `example.com/?fname=John&lname=Doe&id=1234`

How can I stop Google Analytics from tracking the parameter names, `fname` and `lname`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Admin -> Profile -> Profile settings -> Exclude URL Query Parameters (enter your parameters as a comma separated list).